# jQuery adding CSS class to dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, dynamic

I know this question has been asked before but I have some serious weird behaviour here...
I have a DIV containing a list of anchors which are pulled via ajax from a php file (mysqli). I can dynamically add, edit and delete the items (categories) on this list. This works fine. It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of the Item]

However, after a category is created I want to automatically select it. Same goes for edited categories.
And, after the page first loads, the category "Alle" should be selected by default.

I have an external categories-management.js file which contains these functions amongst other things:

```
function selectRootCategory () {
  selectedcategoryname = "Alle";
  categegorySelected = 0;
  $("#training_management_categories_items>ul>li>a").removeClass('categories_selected');
  $('#training_management_categories_list_a_all').addClass('categories_selected');
}
function selectEditedCategory() {
  categorySelected = 1;
  categoryid = 'training_management_categories_list_a_' + selectedcategoryid.toString();
  $("#training_management_categories_items>ul>li>a").removeClass('categories_selected');
  $('#'+categoryid).addClass('categories_selected');
}
```

On the main page I call this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    GetCategories();
    CheckIfCategoryChecked();
    selectRootCategory();
});
```

So basically, what should happen when the page first loads, the category "Alle" should be selected. This doesn't work though.
I would think I got the function wrong, BUT if I delete an Item, the `selectRootCategory()`-function is called, too and **then it works.** This is the function in which it works (housing in categories-management.js, too):

```
function submitDeleteCategory() {
  var url = './ajax/training_management_data.php';
  $('#delete_category_dialog_error').hide();
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      action: 'delete_category',
      category_id: selectedcategoryid,
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data) {
      if (data == 'success') {
        GetCategories();
        CheckIfCategoryChecked();
        selectRootCategory(); //THIS WORKS
        categorySelected = 0;

        $('#delete_category_dialog').dialog('close');
      }
      else {
        $('#delete_category_dialog_error').html('<b>Fehler:</b><br>Fehler beim Löschen der Kategorie.')
        $('#delete_category_dialog_error').show( "blind" ,300);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

However, the `selectEditedCategory()`-function never works (which is called after you edited or created a category so it gets selected) though the given variable (`categoryid`) is correct, tested with alert. The function that calls `selectEditedCategory` is also placed in categories-management.js.

So my questions are:

1. Why does `selectRootCategory()` work when it is called via success-function in the delete-dialog but not when called via `$document.ready()`?
2. Why doesn't `selectEditedCategory()` work at all?

BTW don't get fooled by the `categegorySelected` variable, this is meant to determine if the edit- and delete-button are enabled or not. "Alle" is a fake category which contains all items from all categories and cannot be deleted or edited ("Alle" means "all" in German).
I'm using jquery-1.10.2.

Edit: To make things more clear: The ids on the items are correctly set when I call `GetCategories();`. This function does the following:

```
function GetCategories()
{
  var url = './ajax/training_management_data.php';
  $('#training_management_categories_items').html('<ul style="list-style: none; margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px; padding:0px;" id="training_management_categories_items_ul"></ul>');
  $('#training_management_categories_items_ul').append(' \
    <li class="training_management_categories_list"> \
      <a href="" class="training_management_categories_list_a" id="training_management_categories_list_a_all">Alle</a> \
    </li> \
  ');
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      action: 'get_categories',
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data) {
      $.each(data, function(index, data) {
        $('#training_management_categories_items_ul').append(' \
          <li class="training_management_categories_list"> \
            <a href="" class="training_management_categories_list_a" data-id="'+data.id+'" id="training_management_categories_list_a_'+data.id+'">'+data.name+'</a> \
          </li> \
        ');     
      });
    }
  });
}
```

It works fine which is proven by the fact that I can delete and edit the categories (the functions to do so require the id of the element. However I read the ID not via the ID field as this contains a string but by the attribute "data-id" which only contains the ID (as you see in above code). So the problem lies solely at the jQuery part and not at the ajax-part.

Edit2: When I add selectRootCategory() to the success-function of GetCategories(), it works on page load. But I still don't get why it doesn't work with document.ready(). I cannot use it in `GetCategories()`, though because it would de-select any item and select "Alle" instead.

I can still not get selectedEditedCategory to work.
The var `categoryid` contains a valid ID though, e.g. `training_management_categories_list_a_70`.

Comment: What are your console errors? have you tried running the function through the console and seeing if it runs the way it should?

Comment: @Adjit No errors, if I run it manually it works.

Comment: So I presume that the reason `selectRootCategory()` is not working in your `$(document).ready()` function because that will only run once, most likely before your dynamic elements are loaded in. So what you should do is use an ajax callback to determine when certain data has been loaded. The functions works in your other function because of when it is executed. Try putting a `console.log('inside selected root');` inside of your function to see if it is actually executing the function, just not adding or removing the classes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the data coming back from the server and add a class to it.

like

```
  $.ajax({
    ...
    success:function(data){
        $.each(data,function(singleData){
           $(singleData).addClass('blahblah');
        });
    }
    ...
  });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't work since the data coming back from the server is just the ID of the element which was created or altered. To get the list I use another function `GetCategories()` which adds the IDs to the list items. This still doesn't explain why selectRootCategory() works when it's called within the delete-function but not when it's called by document.ready().

Comment: Not that easy to add a fiddle for this because it's a pretty huge construct. I added all relevant information I think.

Comment: The 2 points, point 1 being: "Why does selectRootCategory() work when it is called via success-function in the delete-dialog but not when called via $document.ready()?"